# Terraform: Failed to unlock state: failed to retrieve lock info: unexpected end of JSON input

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-aws

- Terraform v0.13.5
- provider aws v3.7.0
- Backend: AWS S3+DynamoDB

`terraform plan` was aborted, and now it cannot acquire the state lock. I'm trying to release it manually but get error:

```
terraform force-unlock -force xxx-xxx-xx-dddd

Failed to unlock state: failed to retrieve lock info:
unexpected end of JSON input
```

The state file looks complete and passes json syntax validation successfully.

How to fix that?

Comment: what ended up being the underlying issue?

Comment: @jbooker The answer is below :)

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Solution: double-check you're in correct terraform workspace.

Comment: The error message could state this

Comment: So let's make error messages in our apps more clear and troubleshooting-friendly!

Comment: Got me, this one!

Comment: Where is the correct directory?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue. In my case, there were more than 1 `.tfstate` files in the working directory. This was causing the problem.

1- Ensure you have only 1 `.tfstate` file in the working directory

2- Ensure .tfstate file is valid.

Answer (score 0):

I had to switch to the right workspace and issue the command terraform force-unlcok -force  to get away with the issue.